# accounting.js format number with fixed width

Tags: javascript

I am currently playing around with accounting.js and I have a problem about it.

The problem I encountered is that I would like to apply function in accounting  called formatMoney on top of a number so that the number looks nice, also,  I would like to keep the number as fixed width.

From what I know, in Javascript, we have a function called toPrecision(), which will transfer a number to a fixed width format.

How can I combine them together?

For example, if I have a number var number = 12345.67. By applying number.toPrecision(6), I would get 12345.6. By using accounting.formatMoney(12345.67, {precision:2}). I would get 12,345.67. But how can I merge the result of toPrecision into accounting.js to get the desired number 12,345.6. (The precision will vary according to how big the number is so I am not able to alway pass precision value to formatMoney).

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsbin.com/dumuvavisu/1/edit?js,console

```
var number = 12345.67;

var a = accounting.formatMoney(number.toPrecision(6))
var b = a.substring(a.length-1,0);

console.log(b); // <-- "$12,345.7"
```

Comment: the result from the link gives me ($12,345.70), which actually has 7 digits width (equivalent to toPrecision(7)), I am looking for  ($12,345.7)